# How to access declared variable from app.component to other components?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to Typescript and Angular 2. I tried to look for an answer in the web but it seems they don't work for me.

Say I have an app.component as shown below:

```
export class AppComponent{
    cartPayableAmount = 0;

    ........
}
```

---

```
in my app.component.html, the cartPayableAmount is used here

<div> {{cartPayableAmount}} </div>
```

Now I want to access the cartPayableAmount entity in other class as shown below:  So when ever I envoke TestHere() the value for cartPayableAmount will change and it will reflect at the app.component.html.

```
export class BuyTestComponent {
    TestHere() {
        // should update cart PayableAmount here.....
        cartPayableAmount  = "Some value"
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new service, maybe called `ShoppingCart`, that holds that value. And then it can be injected into your components.

But in your example, `cartPayableAmount` is a computed value, so you'll want it to be a method or Observable that computes it instead of a class property.

Comment: I actually have a method in app.component that computes the for cartPayableAmount.  But that methods is only used inside app.component.  I haven't tried the Observable implementation yet.  I will give a try on that.  Thanks

Comment: Even if that method is only used in one place, you should consolidate all shopping cart logic to one service.